# Logical Arrays - In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have three matrices, A, B and C. When B is larger than A, I want to saturate the value with A. It says that the number of elements in I (which is (B > A)) must be the same as the number of elements in A. I checked below and they are the same.

```
>> A = [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 5 5 5];
>> B = [2 2 2; 2 2 2; 2 2 2];
>> C(B > A) = A
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

>> numel(B > A)

ans =

     9

>> numel(A)

ans =

     9

>> numel(A>B)

ans =

     9
```

It is also strange that this works.

```
>> C(B < A) = A

C =

     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
```

I just figured it out...

> > C(B>A) = B(B>A)

C =

```
 5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why is because `B > A` is **never satisfied**, and produces the empty set.  This will produce the empty matrix (`[]`).  Every element of `B` is actually **smaller** than `A`.  As such, this is equivalent to performing:

```
C([]) = A;
```

You are trying to assign `A` to **nowhere** in the matrix, and those dimensions don't match.  The reason why `B < A` works is because every value of `B` is less than `A`, and so the assignment of `A` will work here.  In general, you need to make sure that the total number of elements you are accessing on the right side of the expression **must equal** the same number of elements on the left hand side of the expression you want to assign the elements to.

As you have mentioned in your comments, doing:

```
C(B > A) = B(B > A)
```

will work.  This is equivalent to doing:

```
C([]) = B([]);
```

... essentially, you are performing nothing, so this is a safe operation.  No values are being accessed in `B` are being assigned to locations in `A`.

Answer (score 3):

B>A is a logical 3x3 matrix, but C(B>A) is the empty set, and you are assigning a 3x3 matrix to it. Thus the error.
Try

```
C(B>A)=A(B>A);
```

On the other hand, C(B < A) is C, a 3x3 matrix, so C(B < A) is C, to which you can assign A.

Comment: +1 - Looks like we posted at roughly the same time! (~ 3 seconds apart!)