# matlab code that previously worked using strcmp to pull values associated with strings out of a cell array now does not work

Tags: matlab, strcmp, cell-array

This is an old code I have used before but I simply modified it for a new set of data. I keep getting the error at the bottom though and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I put the entire code below.

```
sites = importdata('genes_with_mir148_sites.txt');

Data = importdata('gene_exp_LFC_table.txt');
names = Data.textdata
LFC = Data.data

C = intersect(names, sites)

LFCcell = {names, LFC}
L = zeros(length(C),1);
for i1=1:length(C)
L(i1)=LFC(strcmp(C(i1),names));
end

Sites = {C,L}
```

And I get the error: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same.

Comment: Also, in case it is relevant, names and LFC both are 13696x1. C is 1975x1.

Comment: Which line is the error happening in?  Also, this could be related to my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702385/logical-arrays-in-an-assignment-ai-b-the-number-of-elements-in-b-and-i-mu/24702556#24702556 .  You need to make sure that the total number of elements being assigned to the left side of the expression equal the right side.

Comment: I believe the error is in the for loop. I generate C just fine and I generate L but it is all zeros still, so it is something following that.

Also, I don't understand how the total number being assigned to the left and right side could be anything but the same since is is L(i1) and the inside of the right side is C(i1). Could you explain more?

Comment: Actually the first 22 positions in L have values and then it is all zeros so it is erroring in the middle

Comment: I don't really understand how your link is related. Could you please explain. I am really stuck.

Comment: Can you provide code for `LFC` as well as your text files?  I would like to reproduce the error on my end.  The link may be related because the error you are getting matches with the error that is on my post.

Comment: The code for LFC is on the 4th line. And THANK YOU .. how do I add my text files on here though?

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  I thought `LFC` was a function.  You can use a public file sharing website.  Try: http://www.files.com/

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20605795/genes_with_mir148_seed.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20605795/gene_exp_LFC_table.txt

Comment: I found out why.  The reason why is because there is a case where `LFC(strcmp(C(i1),names));` produces **two** numbers when `L(i1)` is expecting an assignment of only one number.  What happens if you get **two** matches instead of one?  Is `gene_exp_LFC_table.txt` all supposed to have **unique** strings?  There is a duplicate of: `2810417H13Rik` in `gene_exp_LFC_table.txt`.

Comment: Specifically, when `i1 = 23`, the indices of `C(23)` that best match with `names` are located at indices `12649, 13043`.  You will have to write logic that either chooses only one of these indices, or rewrite your logic to handle two.  As such, this is related to my post.  The left side is trying to assign **one** number to `C(23)` when the right side of your expression is a vector of **two** elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our comments discussion, the core reason is this statement:

```
L(i1)=LFC(strcmp(C(i1),names));
```

The amount of elements you are trying to assign on the left side of your expression do not equal the right side of your expression.

Given the links to your text files in your comments, this occurs at `i1 = 23`, with the name `2810417H13Rik` in the `sites` cell array.  When trying to find a match in `names`, there are **two** matches.  These are found at indices 12649 and 13043.  When pulling the numerical data at these locations, you are in fact producing a 2 x 1 array.  As such `L(i1)` is expecting a single element when you are actually trying to assign a `2 x 1` array to this element.

As such, I have two recommendations for you to avoid this error:

1. Is every name in `gene_exp_LFC_table` supposed to be unique?  If it is, then you need to remove one of these rows for your current code to work.
2. Change `L` to be a `cell` array to allow for uneven assignment of values per cell.  This will allow you to have multiple matches per name should this be encountered.

Comment: How would you go about converting L into a cell array? Would it be:
    L = cell(length(C),1);

And then how would these values be organized? 

If I am forced to look up gene names initially, but I use them to find a chr location for which there are no duplicates, and then I use this to find the associated values...is there a way to get just a vector of these chr locations for all future uses from an initial query using the gene names?

Comment: So I don't know if I am doing this right but I tried 
LFCcell = {names, LFC}
L = zeros(length(C),1);
for i1=1:length(C)
L(i1)=LFC(strcmp(C(i1),names));
end

And it says "Conversion to cell from double is not possible." How do I make sure it is pulling from LFCcell?

Comment: Try doing this: `L(i1)=LFC(strcmp(C{i1},names));`.  Note that you are using `{}` to access cell elements.  I'm assuming `C` is a cell array.

Comment: Same error. 

I have an extra column in my original txt file now with unique strings. I want to pull all of these out for my gene names which are not unique. 
`Fpkmcell = {Fpkm_Xloc,Fpkm_names,Fpkm_q1,Fpkm_q2,Fpkm_q3,Fpkm_q4}

L = []

for i1=1:length(mir148_sites_exp)
    L(i1)=Fpkm_Xloc(strcmp(mir148_sites_exp(i1),Fpkm_names));

end`
with or without your suggested change I get error: 
The following error occurred converting from cell to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.